# How to avoid duplication of authorization code logic

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authorization

I've written a custom authorization attribute derived from [System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx). I'm using it successfully from my controllers to restrict the access to certain features.

```
public class ArticleController : Controller
{
    [CustomAuthorize(Role.Administrator)]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
       // ...
    }
}
```

And that works fine. Now I want to show or hide HTML elements according to the same authorization logic. For example, in my view "Article", I want to hide the action button "Delete" if the user is not a administrator. I've written something like that:

```
<ul id="menu">
   <li>@if (User.IsInRole(Role.Administrator)) { 
          @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Article", new { id = article.ID }, null)
       } </li>
</ul>
```

It works fine as well, but it creates code logic duplication because I need to specify twice the necessary credientials to perform an action:

- In the controller to block or allow the action.
- In the view to show or hide the action link.

What is the best way to avoid this duplication? Is there any way to reuse my custom authorization attribute from views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A custom helper should be the best option, something like:

```
@Html.SecureActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Article")
```

This helper would check on some kind of service to see if the current user/role has permission on this link.

Answer (score 1):

Make the menu a partial view .

Answer (score 1):

I would create custom html helper for this.

```
public MvcHtmlString AuthorizedActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
string actionName, ... , Role role)
```

And if you feel the Role parameter is redundant, you may inspect the controller action using Reflection and determine allowed roles automatically.